# Jailbroken iPad Apps missing

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, bug, cydia

After jailbreaking my iPad everything went well until one day pages glitched and i has to do a hard reset(pressing home button and lock button) after that all my apps were erased except for Cydia and Stock Apps. I tried many different way to fix it but nothing worked. Than i reset all the settings. After that my Cydia is gone too, the missing apps are still taking storage and my iPad is still jailbroken, anyone now how do i get the apps back? Thanks. My iPad is iPad 4 32GB, white WIFI. Jailbroken with evasion7 using 7.0.4 system.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down the Volume + button while booting up your phone. This should completely disable your jailbreak (in order to get it back you would need to reboot your phone regularly). If your phone now works, then it is an issue with your jailbreak substrate or a tweak. This will at least allow you to narrow down your issue.